# Synonym für "didaktische Kompetenz"

Tags: single-word-request, noun, synonym

Ich suche ein Substantiv, das "die Fähigkeit, Wissen vermitteln zu können" bezeichnet. Ich habe bisher nur "didaktische Kompetenz" gefunden und suche bisher erfolglos nach einem einzelnen Begriff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mein Vorschlag ist `Lehrvermögen`.

Sicherlich ein selten gebrauchtes Wort, aber Google findet [doch](http://books.google.de/books?id=38dZE619uy0C&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=LEHRVERM%C3%96GEN&source=bl&ots=tAuNxgsbsd&sig=sdXgNwyl6RLAQ0VZ7KvLDGGGlxA&hl=de&sa=X&ei=IF1mVMnlGIfzPNbHgdAN&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=LEHRVERM%C3%96GEN&f=false) [eine](http://www.ku.de/ggf/geschichte/didgesch/lehre/) [Reihe](http://www.abada-berlin.de/index.php?id=9) [von](http://www.elote.de/reisen.htm) [Seiten](http://www.scilogs.de/relativ-einfach/bildung-und-ansteckender-enthusiasmus/2/), auf denen es im Sinne von didaktischer Kompetenz gebraucht wird.

Von der wörtlichen Bedeutung her käme auch noch [Lehrbefähigung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehrbef%C3%A4higung) in Betracht, das aber schon als Fachbegriff im deutschen Hochschulrecht besetzt ist.

Eine Alternative wäre auch noch `Erklärvermögen`. Auch hier wärest Du nicht [der](http://forum.nachhilfe-vermittlung.com/index.php?a=s&showDETAILofID=8932&show_uid=8932&ort=Karlsruhe&fach=la&LID=8932&l=gre) [Erste](http://books.google.de/books?id=6-28grR6sOsC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=erkl%C3%A4rverm%C3%B6gen&source=bl&ots=kky6_xHh0D&sig=E1bexm15kEguLXQZtC6HHns8z60&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ZF5mVJnnBIbXPPHIgPAD&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=erkl%C3%A4rverm%C3%B6gen&f=false), der es gebraucht.

Eine "Schummellösung" wäre "Didaktik-Kompetenz", aber wenn Dir das gefallen würde, hättest Du vermutlich nicht gefragt.

Statt der Fähigkeit eine Person mit dieser Fähigkeit zu beschreiben kommt für Dich nicht in Betracht, oder? Sonst wären ganz klassisch "Lehrer" oder etwas seltener "Erklärer" auch noch Kandidaten.

Comment: Lehren impliziert für mich in ein Gefälle: Ich Lehrer, du Schüler. Ich suche nach einem Wort, das als "Team-Tugend" die Fähigkeit zur Wissensvermittlung unter Gleichen beschreibt. Wir werden uns wohl mit Wissenstransfer oder Wissensvermittlung begnügen.

Answer (score 1):

Ein etabliertes Wort fällt mir dafür nicht ein. Als Gegenstück zu "lernfähig" lässt sich

> Lehrfähigkeit

bilden. Dann gibt es noch die

> Lehrhaftigkeit,

die etymologisch zwar nichts mit "Fähigkeit" zu tun hat, diese aber implizieren kann. Zusätzlich ist ersteres nicht für Sachen geeignet (etwa Lernprogramme), während ich letzteres auf Personen bezogen eher im Sinne von "lehrerhaft" vertehen würde.